# Anything that expected within the last 10 days back should be received if not ignore them in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, sql-date-functions

I need to ignore data anything that expected within the last 10 days back should be received if not ignore it. I am not sure how to write this in SQL. I have EXPDATE column. I am not sure my statement correct or not.

I believe the logic should be like this

> Expected Date + 10 Days < Today`s date?

`GETDATE() < DATEADD(DAY, +10, GETDATE())` - I found this online but where can I plug in my ExpectedDate column?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: " I am not sure my statement correct or not".  Where's your SQL statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it either way-
First add 10 days to EXPDATE and compare it with todays date like below.

```
select * from MyTable Where DATEADD(DAY, 10, EXPDATE) < GETDATE()
```

The other way, you can substract 10 days from today and compare it with EXPDATE.

```
select * from MyTable Where DATEADD(DAY, -10, GETDATE()) > EXPDATE
```

I would prefer 2nd one and would use variable to calculate 10 days back date as it's constant and then use it in where clause like below.

```
Declare @myDate datetime
SET @myDate = DATEADD(DAY, -10, GETDATE())
select * from MyTable Where @myDate  > EXPDATE
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Now, I have a different error due to the type difference. GETDATE is datetime and EXPDATE is decimal. I converted both to varchar.

Comment: what is the error? and share the sample of EXPDATE value. You just need to convert EXPDATE to datetime using suitable format based on EXPDATE format.